# tapGestureRecognizer.location brings nil in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

In my `swift` app I created class that delegates `UICollectionViewController`. Additionally, I have other class responsible for handling 'UICollectionReusableView`.

So in the first class I have a method:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! UserProfileHeaderCollectionReusableView
```

and thanks to this - in this method - I have access to all buttons and labels stored in the header view, e.g.:

```
headerView.followButton.isHidden = false

headerView.followButton.addGestureRecognizer(
           UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(followThisUser)))
```

later on, I have a method `followThisUser`:

```
@objc private func followThisUser(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    if (!doIFollow) {

        followUser(userId)
    } else {
        unfollowUser(userId)
    }
}
```

and based on the flag `doIFollow` I'm performing specific method.

I would like to give user a feedback when he presses a button and change it's color as soon as he presses it. I tried to access this button by adding:

```
    let tapLocation = tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.userProfileCollectionView)

    let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.userProfileCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: tapLocation)! as NSIndexPath
```

to the `followThisUser` method, but it throws error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How can I access the `followButton` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, since you set a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your button - is get the original `UIView` from the gesture recognizer in your handler method. Something like this to turn the button background color orange:

```
@objc private func buttonTap(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    // Get the view that the gesture is attached to
    let button = tapGestureRecognizer.view

    // Change the view's background color
    button?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

}
```

Now if your original button is a `UIButton`, and you need to use some of the special properties of the `UIButton` class, you can cast the view as a `UIButton`

```
@objc private func buttonTap(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    // Get the view that the gesture is attached to
    let button = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIButton

    // Change the UIButton's title label text color
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.orange, for: .normal)

}
```

Comment: @user3766930 - Sure thing! Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one**

```
var tapGesture : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "processTapGesture:")
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

**Handle gesture**

```
func processTapGesture (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended
        {
            var point:CGPoint = sender.locationInView(collectionView)
            var indelPath:NSIndexPath =collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)
            if indexPath
            {
                print("image taped")
            }
            else
            {
               //Do Some Other Stuff Here That Isnt Related;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, however `var indelPath...` line still throws me a `nil` here :(

Comment: Are you getting the tap action or location?